# 何をする関数なのか分からない

Tags: c

課題について質問です。
以下の関数は何を行うものなのかがよくわかりません。

```
int pal(char *s)
{
    char *t=s;
    while (*t!='\0'){
        t++;
    }
    t--; 
    while (s<=t){
        if(*s!=*t){
            return 0;
        }
        s++;
        t--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

自分の考えでは、大文字を小文字に,小文字を大文字に変えるプログラムだと思ったのですが、（例 `pal("abcxyz")`->ABCXYZ)違いますか。

Comment: ご質問にいくつかマイナス票が集まっているもののどこを改善すべきかのコメントが無いので、どうしたらもっと良い質問になるかご意見を募ってみる質問をメタと呼ばれるサイトに投稿してみました。もし何かしら回答が集まれば、今後質問する際の参考にしてみてください。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3228/19110

Answer (score 6, accepted):

大文字を小文字に、小文字を大文字に変える関数ではないです。ではどのような関数でしょうか。この回答では挙動を確かめるやり方のひとつを紹介します。

まず関数の型を見ると、文字列 `char *` を受け取って整数 `int` を返しています。

```
int pal(char *s)
```

続いて関数の中身を見ると、色々と処理をしつつ最終的に `0` か `1` を返しています。まずはこの `0` と `1` が何なのかを考えることが理解に繋がりそうです。

この関数は危険な関数では無いので、実際に実行してみて挙動を確かめてみてください。たとえば下のような感じです。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int pal(char *s)
{
...
}

int main(void)
{
    char *input = malloc(128);
    int result;

    sprintf(input, "%s", "abcde");  /* ここを色々と変えて挙動を確かめる */    
    result = pal(input);
    printf("input: %s\nresult: %d\n", input, result);

    free(input);
    return 0;
}
```

`"abcde"` と書かれている部分を "abcd" とか "abcba" とか "aaaa" とか変えてみて、出力がどう変わるか確かめてみてください。もしかしたら挙動が推測できるかもしれません。

その上でもう一度ソースコードを見て、どういう動き方をしているのか 1 行 1 行確認してみてください。

キーポイント：

- 最初の `while` ループではポインタ `t` が指し示している場所をずらしています。C 言語の文字列は最後に `\0` が入っているので、ここでは `t` を `s` の最後の 1 バイト (`\0` の直前のバイト) まで動かしています。
- 2 つ目の `while` ループが鬼門です。与えられた文字列の先頭を指しているポインタ `s` と、末尾を指しているポインタ `t` を同時に動かしています。1 回のループで、`s` は次のバイトに進み、`t` は前のバイトに戻ります。ただしもしその指し示している先が異なるバイトであれば、即座に `return 0` です。最終的に `s` が `t` を追い越せば (`s <= t` を満たさなくなれば) ループは終わりです。つまり、文字列の真ん中まで来たら終わりです。

  - よく分からなければ、実際に紙の上に手で `s` と `t` がどうなっているのかを書いてみて、挙動を確認してみてください。ループが 1 回まわるごとに、どのように動いているでしょうか。

答え合わせのために、結局 `pal` は何をする関数なのかを隠して書いておきます。

> 関数 `pal` は、与えられた ASCII 文字列 `s` が回文であれば `1` を、そうでなければ `0` を返す関数です。`pal` というのは「回文」を表す英単語 "palindrome" から取ったのでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。とてもわかり易い説明で私にも理解ができました。いろいろな文字に打ち替えてみたところ、”abcde" のときは0を、"aadaa"のときは1を返したので、「回文ならば１を、回文でなければ０を返す関数」かと思い、答え合わせをしたところ、正解だったので良かったです。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

課題ということですので、１行１行の説明をします。

3行目 ポインターtにｓを代入しているので、この時点でsとtは同じになります。
4行目から7行目 文字列の終わりまでtを進めています。結果として文字列の最後を示しています。
8行目から14行目 sの値とtの値を比較し、不一致の場合0を返します。一致していた場合はｓの頭から次の文字、ｔの最後から一つ前の文字を比較します。それを真ん中の文字まで繰り返します。
不一致が一つも無い場合、while文を抜けます。
最後に１を返します。